# How to organize Vue-JS : Non Javascript way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, project-organization

### How to organize Vue-JS project [files and directory]: Non Javascript way?

Coming from a non-javascript background, I found Vue.js very intuitive and easy to use. My earlier experience in Javascript is with JQuery and vanilla javascript on the browser.

I created an application using Vue , Vue-components and vue router. Everything works fine.

My problem is, I have ended up writing a lot of code in a single index.html file of my project. This file contains over 10 templates that I have created and attached to different component in my app. I want to know that is there a non-javascript way to organize these templates in seperate files.

I see that there are options using webpack and browserify to modularize the project. But coming from non javascript background, I don't find them intuitive. I don't want to go node - npm way because that has its own learning curve and moreover it downloads a dozen of files and dependencies in my project which I don't understand. I am old school and more comfortable downloading the files and including them in the webpages.

So probably, you understand where I am going to. I need a solution where I could put my templates as separate files and read those files in the different components.

What I have tried :

- Declaring the templates inside my components. But writing all that html inside the component is not that clean. It also, makes my JS file too huge. I am better in putting all data in the index.html instead.
- Storing template as smaller chunk "homepage.html","about.html" and in my components, using $.get / $.load to read different components in ready function of the component. This works but I still have to fire an additional ajax call for each component which is not efficient.

Please refrain from suggesting the obvious node-npm [webpack and browserify] way. I know thats what is supported by Vue but this needs a learning curve and complete setup. Answer to this question would actually help other developers who hesitate going the node-npm way.

Please shout back if you need more clarifications to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The options you've mentioned are your only real ones... the HTML of the template needs to be available when it's needed, so you either have to have it within your html file off the bat, or load it using AJAX or an in-browser loader like RequireJS (and this extension that allows it to load HTML https://github.com/requirejs/text).

In-file templates make sense for very small projects.  As your project grows, you'll need to start using the tools that are built for this. NPM rocks and every JS package that you'll ever need can be included in your project in seconds.

Comment: Well true.. I do understand that there seems to be a valid reason to learn the basics of node-npm and webpack. But thats way out of my league + the learning curve and the installations and dependencies would take me forever to get my app complete. So I am refraining from diving into another sea of options and would like to know if there are some old school way to do this.

Comment: Not trying to push you into it but I laracasts.com really helped when I was transitioning away from "traditional" methods.

Answer (score 0):

I highly encourage you to try the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)

It *does* use node, npm, webpack and downloads dozens of files. *Which you've you've explicitly asked for not to use*, so let me clarify:

The Vue CLI takes care of the complexity and configures webpack for you.
You don't even have to know it's using webpack.

It's very developer friendly (it even has a [built-in gui](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui)) and lowers the barrier to entry compared configuring a webpack config.

I hope you'll also find it "intuitive and easy to use".